# Как пишутся названия праздников?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Как правильно писать названия праздников: что там с большой буквы, а что с маленькой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В названиях праздников с большой буквы всегда пишется только первое слово (либо оба, если второе - имя собственое).
Примеры: *Новый год, День строителя, Рождество Христово*.
Исключение - День Победы.
Если название начинает на цифру, то с большой буквы пишется второе слово.
Примеры: *8 Марта, 1 Мая*.
При этом такие праздники, как "день рождения" и "день ангела", пишутся с маленькой буквы (оба слова).